# What php file is the div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper" located in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to rearrange the layout for my WooCommerce pages, specifically the individual product page but I can't find where the HTML code is. I'm looking for:

```
<div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
```

I've had a search using my text editor across all available files and it cannot be found but it's very clear that it is in the inspected elements. Is there somewhere I can find it or do I just have to override the whole thing? If so, how?

Comment: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php` is the file you are looking for

Comment: Thank you, that helped. But I'm looking to move this div below the related products on the the single product page so I'm really looking for the file where the divs; <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper"> AND  <div class='related products"> live.

Comment: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/related.php` contains <div class='related products">

Answer (score 1):

If you want to design the pages of WooCommerce copy the folder `plugins/woocommerce/templates/` to your theme folder and rename it 'WooCommerce' would be: `themes/mytheme/woocommerce`. That way you can modify the templates and update the plugin changes are not erased.

For more information [read here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)